# Powershell to execute SQL SCRIPTS

Tags: powershell

anyone know how to rewrite below code, so it can invoke sql script. For instance, instead of put 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName' in the powershell script, I would like to put it into sql file.

```
$Path = "D:\AdminStuff\PowerShell\Password\Password.txt"
$uid = 'sa'
$pwd = Get-Content D:\AdminStuff\PowerShell\Password\Password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$pwd.MakeReadOnly()


$creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential($uid,$pwd)

$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = "Server=SLB-CLMFZ52;Database=master;"
$con.Credential = $creds
$con.Open()

$sql = "SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName"

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$con)
$rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
while($rdr.Read())
{
 $rdr["ServerName"].ToString()
}


$con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you *can* use the `SqlCredential`, `SqlConnection`, and `SqlCommand` .NET classes as you show in your question, there are simpler alternatives. It is a lot less work, for example, to use the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet instead. `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is essentially the venerable `sqlcmd` utility with a PowerShell disguise. Thus, assuming your query was in a file myScript.sql, you can just run this--the `InputFile` parameter provides the means to store your SQL in a separate file as you requested:

```
$InvokeParams = @{
    Server = 'SLB-CLMFZ52'
    Database = 'Master'
    Username = 'sa'
    Password = 'xyz'
    InputFile = 'myScript.sql'
}
Invoke-SqlCmd @InvokeParams
```

Now the obvious problem with that, though, is the password must be in plain text. (Of course, the password in the OP was in plain text in a file, as well. :-) Unfortunately `Invoke-Sqlcmd` does not work with PowerShell credential objects, which would have made it a lot more secure. The only reasonable workaround to get some security is to use Windows Authentication instead of SQL authentication. Then you could, for example, omit the username and password, and the query will be invoked with secure credentials:

```
$InvokeParams = @{
    Server = 'SLB-CLMFZ52'
    Database = 'Master'
    InputFile = 'myScript.sql'
}
Invoke-SqlCmd @InvokeParams
```

To use the cmdlet just `Import-Module sqlps`. For the basics of `Invoke-SqlCmd` take a look at [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) and for a more in-depth treatment, including the vagaries of sqlps, see part 1 of my [Practical PowerShell for SQL Server Developers and DBAs](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/practical-powershell-for-sql-server-developers-and-dbas-%E2%80%93-part-1/#executing) article.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my scripts and using Invoke-sqlcmd and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

What about something simple like this:

```
$sql=get-content $filename
```